# npm run dev failing on Mac due to webpack serve command failing

Tags: npm, webpack

I am trying to run the "npm run dev" on my Mac but facing the below errors. I have already fixed the webpack installation, npm installation, etc. required but am stuck here.

```
MacBook-Air:Exercise workhouse$ npm run dev

> @ dev /Users/workhouse/Desktop/Personal Projects/3JS/Lesson 4/Exercise
> webpack serve --config ./bundler/webpack.dev.js

[webpack-cli] Unable to load '@webpack-cli/serve' command
[webpack-cli] TypeError: devServerFlags is not iterable
    at /Users/workhouse/Desktop/Personal Projects/3JS/Lesson 4/Exercise/node_modules/@webpack-cli/serve/lib/index.js:28:43
    at WebpackCLI.makeCommand (/Users/workhouse/Desktop/Personal Projects/3JS/Lesson 4/Exercise/node_modules/webpack-cli/lib/webpack-cli.js:98:31)
    at ServeCommand.apply (/Users/workhouse/Desktop/Personal Projects/3JS/Lesson 4/Exercise/node_modules/@webpack-cli/serve/lib/index.js:10:19)
    at loadCommandByName (/Users/workhouse/Desktop/Personal Projects/3JS/Lesson 4/Exercise/node_modules/webpack-cli/lib/webpack-cli.js:378:35)
    at Command.<anonymous> (/Users/workhouse/Desktop/Personal Projects/3JS/Lesson 4/Exercise/node_modules/webpack-cli/lib/webpack-cli.js:694:23)
    at Command.listener [as _actionHandler] (/Users/workhouse/Desktop/Personal Projects/3JS/Lesson 4/Exercise/node_modules/webpack-cli/node_modules/commander/index.js:426:31)
    at Command._parseCommand (/Users/workhouse/Desktop/Personal Projects/3JS/Lesson 4/Exercise/node_modules/webpack-cli/node_modules/commander/index.js:1002:14)
    at Command.parse (/Users/workhouse/Desktop/Personal Projects/3JS/Lesson 4/Exercise/node_modules/webpack-cli/node_modules/commander/index.js:801:10)
    at Command.parseAsync (/Users/workhouse/Desktop/Personal Projects/3JS/Lesson 4/Exercise/node_modules/webpack-cli/node_modules/commander/index.js:828:10)
    at WebpackCLI.run (/Users/workhouse/Desktop/Personal Projects/3JS/Lesson 4/Exercise/node_modules/webpack-cli/lib/webpack-cli.js:711:28)
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 2
npm ERR! @ dev: `webpack serve --config ./bundler/webpack.dev.js`
npm ERR! Exit status 2
```

Comment: Can you please print your package.json?
It is required to check webpack-related packages versions.

Answer (score 0):

This is an issue with the latest @webpack-cli/serve v1.6 version. You can find temporary solutions here: https://githubmemory.com/repo/webpack/webpack-cli/issues/2990?page=1